# MYSQL, assign and read a variable in same statement

Tags: mysql, variables

LINK: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

I was reading mysql documentation and I got really confused about that general rule!

Documentation:

> As a general rule, OTHER THAN IN SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.

Ok, so does it means that I can use SET statement to assign AND READ a user variable? right? BUT when I try it...

```
SET @a:=1, @b:=@a+1;
SELECT @a,@b; # @a = 1, @b = NULL
```

Looks like the SET statement have the same problem of any other statement for assign and read user variables in the same statement.

```
SET @a:=1;
SET @b:=@a+1;
SELECT @a,@b; # @a=1 , @b=2
```

So, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation is simply wrong. As you've shown, there's not really any difference between `SET` and `SELECT` in this regard.

Comment: and this is not ok either: SET @a:=1, @b:=@a+1;
so what exacly is the difference between a SET statement and SELECT?

that part: "OTHER THAN IN SET statements" makes no sense

Comment: I know, that's in your question.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for replying. :P